# Elastic Beanstalk and Rails – initializing multiple times?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my RoR (4.2.6) application to ElasticBeanstalk, it appears that the initialization process is getting run four times. This is impacting the way I rely on a singleton instance of a job Scheduler object (using [Rufus Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler)).

In a couple of initializer files and in `application.rb`, I added a few log statements:

Here:

```
# /config/initializers/scheduler.rb
require 'rufus-scheduler'

::Rufus_lockfile = "/tmp/.rufus-scheduler.lock"

::Scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton(
  :lockfile => Rufus_lockfile
)

Rails.logger.info "1: started Scheduler #{Scheduler.object_id}"
```

And here:

```
# /config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb

Rails.logger.info "2: some other initializer"
```

And here:

```
# /config/application.rb

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    ... 

    config.after_initialize do
      Rails.logger.info "3: after app is initialized"
    end

  end
end
```

After I run `eb deploy` and it completes, this is what I see at the top of `app/log/production.log`:

```
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:08.756302 #18753]  INFO -- : 2: some other initializer
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:08.757252 #18753]  INFO -- : 1: started Scheduler 47235057343600
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:08.896353 #18753]  INFO -- : 3: after app is initialized
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:23.669517 #18817]  INFO -- : 2: some other initializer
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:23.670380 #18817]  INFO -- : 1: started Scheduler 46989489069800
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:23.806154 #18817]  INFO -- : 3: after app is initialized
D, [2016-05-31T10:31:23.969103 #18817] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"^[[0m
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:33.108449 #18897]  INFO -- : 2: some other initializer
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:33.109513 #18897]  INFO -- : 1: started Scheduler 47156425207060
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:33.116500 #18901]  INFO -- : 2: some other initializer
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:33.117374 #18901]  INFO -- : 1: started Scheduler 47156425216940
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:33.790266 #18901]  INFO -- : 3: after app is initialized
I, [2016-05-31T10:31:33.844517 #18897]  INFO -- : 3: after app is initialized
```

So it looks like the initializer files and even the code in my `after_initializer` block are getting run four times... and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question got asked on rufus-scheduler issue system, answered there: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues/208